# Where can I set jenkinsX pod's storage sizes? The pods are running out of storage

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, jenkins-x

I have setup jenkinsx using the jx -import command, and have updated the helm charts and jenkinsfile in the repo to run builds for a nodejs application. JX will spin up a new pod with a nodejs container and jnlp container. At some point in the build, when its pulling docker images, the pod runs out of storage and gets killed with error which can be seen here: https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/3243 . So I attached an NFS drive and created a bind mount from /home/jenkins to NFS drive, and this resolved the issue for nodejs container, but the jnlp container in the pod is still running out of storage. The /dev/xvda1 drive in pod is 32GB and is 98% utilized before the pod crashes. Need a way to increase the pod's storage size.

I have tried adding an NFS volume via the "Manage Jenkins -> "Configure System" in the jenkins UI. This works for nodejs container but not for jnlp container. Need a way to increase storage size for the jenkinx pod.

Here is the github issue with the error logs: https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/3243

Comment: Solution: The /dev/xvda drive is attached directly to the EBS volume so I just have to increase the size of the EBS thats attached to the worker node.

Comment: You should post this comment as an answer then accept it, so your question won't appear unanswered anymore ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: The /dev/xvda drive is attached directly to the EBS volume so I just have to increase the size of the EBS thats attached to the worker node.